# How to show an outline on the selected row in ag-grid?

Tags: css, ag-grid

When a user clicks on a cell in ag-grid, it shows a blue outline on the selected cell. I'd like to change this so that the entire row gets a blue outline when any cell in the row is selected.

The below image is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862009/how-to-disable-selection-of-cells-in-ag-grid) which explains how to remove the blue selection outline from cells in a particular column.

[image]

Code for the above as pasted from the linked question is:

```
this.columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'One', field: 'one' },
  { headerName: 'Two', field: 'two' },
  { headerName: 'I want no cell selection!', 
    field: 'three',   
    suppressNavigable: true,
    editable: false,
  }
];
```

I'm not a CSS whiz, but this seems like a 2-part process:

- Get rid of individual cell outlines for all columns
- Put an outline over the entire row which is selected

So...

1. Is there an easy way to apply the `'no-border'` cellClass mentioned in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862009/how-to-disable-selection-of-cells-in-ag-grid) to all rows/columns without copy-pasting `'no-border'` to every single column header?
2. What would I modify to get the entire row to have that blue outline when it's selected?

I've looked through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40210231/6854489) and [this rowClass documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/) but it seems my CSS isn't sharp enough to implement #2 correctly. (If you need more code, please put a comment. I've got a TypeScript file that supplies GridOptions [such as `suppressCellSelection: true`] to the Grid.)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I can remove the selection border from all cells with this in my CSS:

```
::ng-deep .ag-cell:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

This is the best I could do to highlight rows. It doesn't match the original outline color perfectly, but it's close enough.

```
::ng-deep .ag-row-focus {
  outline: skyblue solid 2px;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

[image: screenshot of outlined row]

(not sure if the `::ng-deep` will be necessary for your application)

*Note: Users may not be able to copy individual cell-contents with this CSS change.*

If you figure out a way to copy the exact cell outline color shown in the image in the question, please share. Apparently it may have something to do with Chrome according to [this Github issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1918).